# Alternative to jQuery's serialize()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, input

I have a lot of `input`s with the same `name` attribute. I know how to get them all as jQuery object!

The `console.log()` prints-out something like this:

```
[
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"people" value=​"33" checked=​"checked">​
, 
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"people" value=​"1" checked=​"checked">​
]
```

After that, I need to send an AJAX request to server that contains all IDs of people (`value` attribute).

Obviously, I can chain `serialize()` to that jQuery object and the result will be like:

```
people=33&people=1
```

...but I'm looking for 'more-friendly' way. 'More-friendly' to PHP, so I can do like:

```
foreach ($_POST['people'] as $people) {

    echo $people;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.serializeArray() might do the trick: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: This works, but, sadly, I don't need the `name` attribute, because it repeats. Nevermind, it does work fine! :)

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work. It works almost! :D The problem is, when passing serialized data (using `serializeArray()`) as 2nd param of `post()` method... it sends only **one** element of array. It does ignore other elements, because `name` attributes are the same.

Comment: You are going to need to add the [] to the field names that repeat then. You can add them in your markup as @jondavidjohn suggested, or programmatically by looping through the results of your serialize array call.

Comment: You shouldn't mark something answered if it didn't answer it.

Answer (score 5):

PHP requires multiple checkboxes of the same name to use bracket notation. Using the following naming convention should allow you to do what you want.

```
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"people[]" value=​"1" checked=​"checked">​
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I'm using AJAX to send those values to server. Not `<input type="submit" />`.

Answer (score 3):

just add `[]` to your names for your checkbox names...

```
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"people[]" value=​"33" checked=​"checked">​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"people[]" value=​"1" checked=​"checked">​
```

Then `$_POST['people']` will be an array of the input's values...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I will answer my question. :)

Loop over jQuery object (where `<input>`s are) and add `value` of the element to an array.

```
var data = [];

$(this).parents('form').find('input[name="people"]').each(function() {

    data.push($(this).val());

});

console.log(data);

$.post('over/the/rainbow', {'people' : data});
```

**Edit:**

In my opinion, @bstakes way is cleaner.